# How to send request disconnect from server to all clients and server still live (python socket)

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

When I disconnect all clients in server, server doesn't continue live. How can I do for living server

`import socket, threading, tkinter`

Server

```
import socket, threading, tkinter
import time

def sendDisconnectAll(my_clients):
    for client in my_clients:
        conn = client[0]
        conn.sendall('Disconnect'.encode('utf8'))
        conn.close()
    
def handle_client(conn, addr):
    while True:
        try:
            request_from_clients = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf8') #sample request
            print(request_from_clients)
            if request_from_clients == 'SignIn':
                conn.sendall('Accept Sign in'.encode('utf8'))
        except:
            print('Client has been shutdown')
            break

my_clients = []
def live_server():
    global thr
    global s
    while True:
        try:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            my_clients.append((conn, addr))
            thr = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
            thr.daemon = True
            thr.start()
        except:
            print("Error")

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen()
print('HOST: ', HOST)
print('PORT: ', PORT)

thr = threading.Thread(target=live_server)
thr.daemon = True
thr.start()
count_time = time.time()
while True:
    now = time.time()
    if (int(now - count_time) + 1) % 10 == 0:       #Disconnect all clients after 10 seconds
        count_time = now
        request = 'Disconnect'
        print('Disconnect all')
        sendDisconnectAll(my_clients)
```

Clients

```
import socket, threading
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def signIn():
    global client
    request = 'SignIn'
    try:
        client.sendall(request.encode('utf8'))
        client.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
    except:
        print('Server has been shutdown')

IP = input("Enter IP: ")
PORT = input("Enter PORT: ")

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    client.connect((IP, int(PORT)))
except:
    print("Can't connect to server")
    client.close()
def live_client():
    global client
    while True:
        print(client.recv(1024).decode('utf8'))
thr = threading.Thread(target=live_client)
thr.daemon = True
thr.start()
app = Tk()
app.title('CLIENT')
but_connect = tk.Button(app, text="SIGN IN",
                            width=20, command=signIn)
but_connect.pack(pady=6)
app.mainloop()
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: You sever the connection by closing the socket, but clients don't get notified of this.  If they have a read pending, the read will return 0 bytes.

Comment: The server can send some data to clients before closing all the client sockets.

Comment: I try to send request 'disconnect' to clients before close the client socket in server source code and make clients receive request 'disconnect' from server in "While True:" but it doesn't work. @TimRoberts

Comment: I try to send request 'disconnect' to clients before close the client socket in server source code and make clients receive request 'disconnect' from server in "While True:" but it doesn't work. @acw1668

Comment: Your clients are doing reads, right?  Your sample code doesn't show that.

Comment: There is no while loop in client code.

Comment: I tried it in threading different from GUI tkinter loop but I get error @TimRoberts

Comment: That is NOT a good enough explanation of what you did and what you tried.  If the code you show is not the code you're running, then we can't really help you.  Show us what you have, and tell us what error you get and where.

Comment: I will edit my question soon

Comment: I had edited my code and question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only add clients to the `my_clients` list. Let's look what happens in server:

- server starts
- it receives one client an adds it to `my_clients`
- on next *disconnect all* operation the socket for that client is closed, but the client remains on the list
- on the following *disconnect all* operation, the main thread of the server tries to write to a closed socket and raises an exception
- as all other threads are daemonic, the application ends.

You must clear the `my_clients` list after closing all the client sockets:

```
def sendDisconnectAll(my_clients):
    for client in my_clients:
        conn = client[0]
        conn.sendall('Disconnect'.encode('utf8'))
        conn.close()
    my_clients.clear()
```

Beware: I did not look at client code...

Comment: My problem is solved! Thank you!